# Nested IF-statements in Lisp with progn

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, nested-if

I have a questions about multiple if-statements in lisp. If `count` is not equal to `n` I want to continue on with the `let` and `if` statements, else I want to do `(= (abs (- row i))` and if that is `t` return nil.

However, I find that whenever `count` is not `n` I will return `nil` because `progn` always returns the last line of code in the block. Please share with me how I can write the program so that I only when `count` is not `n` I will only return `nil` when any of the `or` clauses are `t`.

```
(loop for i below n
      do (if (/= count n)
             (progn
               (let ((tcol (getqueencol i n)))
                 (if (or (= col tcol) (= (abs (- row i)) (abs (- col tcol))))
                     (return-from queen-can-be-placed-here nil))))
           (if (= (abs (- row i)))
               (return-from queen-can-be-placed-here nil))))
```

UPDATED:

Thank you for good response. Yes, indeed I am trying to solve the N queen puzzle :P The problem I have right now is that my control to determine if placing a queen at a certain row and column is not working when the row is empty. That is because `getqueencol` will return `nil` when the row is empty and in `queen-can-be-placed-here` there will be a `(= nil NUMBER)`.

To combat that I tried to make a count variable in `queen-can-be-placed-here` that knows whether a row is empty or not, and that would enable me to not call `getqueencol` on an empty row. The problem is though that I do not know how the check will be in `queen-can-be-placed-here` when a queen is to be added to an empty row.

Here is the code so far:

```
(defvar *board* (make-array '(5 5) :initial-element nil)) 

(defun getqueencol (row n)
"Traverses through the columns of a certain row
 and returns the column index of the queen."
  (loop for i below n
        do (if (aref *board* row i)
               (return-from getqueencol i))))

(defun print-board (n)
"Prints out the solution, e.g. (1 4 2 5 3),
 where 1 denotes that there is a queen at the first 
 column of the first row, and so on."
  (let ((solutionlist (make-list n)))
    (loop for row below n
          do (loop for col below n
                   do (when (aref *board* row col)
                        (setf (nth row solutionlist) col))))
    (print solutionlist)))


(defun queen-can-be-placed-here (row col n)
"Returns t if (row,col) is a possible place to put queen, otherwise nil."
  (let ((count 0))
    (loop for i below n  ;This is the block I added to keep track of if a     row is empty (count = n)
          do (if (not (aref *board* row i))   
                 (setf count (+ 1 count))))

    (loop for i below n
          do (if (/= count n)
                 (let ((tcol (getqueencol i n)))
                   (if (or (= col tcol) (= (abs (- row i)) (abs (- col     tcol))))
                       (return-from queen-can-be-placed-here nil)))
               (if (= (abs (- row i)))   ;Here is where I don't know what to check
                   (return-from queen-can-be-placed-here nil)))))

  (return-from queen-can-be-placed-here t))


(defun backtracking (row n)
"Solves the NxN-queen problem with backtracking"
  (if (< row n)
      (loop for i below n
          do (when (queen-can-be-placed-here row i n)
                  (setf (aref *board* row i) 't)
                  (backtracking (+ row 1) n)
                  (setf (aref *board* row i) 'nil)))
    (print-board n)))

(defun NxNqueen-solver (k)
"Main program for the function call to the recursive solving of the problem"
  (setf *board* (make-array (list k k) :initial-element nil))
  (backtracking 0 k))
```

Comment: what would `(= (abs (- row i)))` be other than `T`? Calling `=` with just one argument seems to be relatively useless.

Comment: Isn't it completely useless? :P No there should be another term there as well. But do you have any idea how can solve the problem with the nested if's?

Comment: **"so that I only when count is not n I will only return nil when any of the or clauses are t"**  I'm not clear what you were trying to say here.

Comment: You never return anything else than `nil`, what are we missing?

Comment: @coredump Yeah, I don't understand that part either, but *do* note that some of the returns are non-local.  Without seeing the enclosing scope (i.e., where **queen-can-be-placed-here** is), we don't really get an idea of what's being returned to where.

Comment: @RichardBerg If you can post the full version, you will have better advices. You are trying to solve the N-queens problem, right? don't be ashamed :-)

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation. @coredump Please see my updated question. Yes, I am trying to solve the N queen problem :P

Comment: @RichardBerg This is far better. I don't have much time right now, sorry, I'll look at this later. Working under stress, or "freaked out", is not your best option. Maybe you will see clearer if you step out from the computer, take a walk and/or try to explain what you did to the proverbial [Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: @coredump Truly appreciate if you could give a some help here. I have gotten inspiration from this solution in C [link](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programs/c-progran-to-implement-n-queens-problem.html), if that is any help. I feel like the code is more or less identical, but mine does not seem to work! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

> I have a questions about multiple if-statements in lisp. If count is
>   not equal to n I want to continue on with the let and if statements,
>   else I want to do (= (abs (- row i)) and if that is t return nil.

Once you start having multiple forms on either branch of an **if**, it's often clearer to use **cond** instead:

```
(cond
  ((/= n count)               ; if n is not count, then ...
   (let ...       
     (return-from ...)))      ; maybe return something
  ((= (abs (- row i)) ...)    ; else if |row-i] = ..., 
   (return-from ...)))        ; return nil
```

That said, you *don't* actually have multiple branches in the *then* part of your **if**.  There's no need to wrap **let** in **progn**.  You can just do:

```
(if (/= count n)
    (let ((tcol (getqueencol i n)))
      (if (or (= col tcol) (= (abs (- row i)) (abs (- col tcol))))
          (return-from queen-can-be-placed-here nil)))
    (if (= (abs (- row i)))
        (return-from queen-can-be-placed-here nil)))
```

As to returning **nil** from the **if**, there are two things to consider. You're using **return-from**, which means that you're performing a non-local exit.  While the *value* of an expression of the form **(if test then)** is **nil** when **test** is false, you're never doing anything with that value.  Actually, it's a fairly common style in Common Lisp to use **when** in the case that there's no *else* part.  That is, **(when test then)** is equivalent to **(if test then nil)** and to **(if test then)**.  It's true that it means **(if ...)** evaluates to **nil**, so **nil** is the value of the **let**, and thus of the **progn**, but you don't actually *do* anything with the value of the **progn**; it's just a form that you're evaluating within the **loop**.

Comment: Thank you for great explanation. Please see my updated question. I am trying to solve N queen puzzle in an AI course.

Answer (score 0):

Each call to backtrack tries to place a queen at each possible column. That means that when you are calling `queen-can-be-placed-here` at row `row`, you can be sure that all rows including `row` that come *after* `row` are empty (you erase the board when backtracking).

So you only need to check if the queen can be placed correctly at current column `col` and current `row` by looking at the subset of the board that has a lesser row.

```
             col
              v
           c0 v  c1

   r0      Q  -  -  -
   r1      -  -  Q  -
  row >>   -  ?  -  -
           -  -  -  -
```

There can be a queen only if, for all *above* rows, `guetqueencol` returns a column that is different from `col` or in a direct diagonal position (the computations with `abs`). So you don't really need to count anything, just ensure that a test is never met.

There are *minor* issues with the code like variable names, so once you are sure everything works as intended you can ask on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for more feedback, if you want.

What I think is the appropriate answer is inside the following spoiler section.

> ```
> (defun queen-can-be-placed-here (row col n)
>     "Returns t if (row,col) is a possible place to put queen, otherwise nil."
>     (loop
>        for r below row
>        for c = (getqueencol r n)
>        never (or (= col c)
>                  (= (abs (- row r))
>                     (abs (- col c))))))
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it works now! What I don't get is why the program finds ALL solutions to the problem. Does each call to `backtracking` find a new solution? What would the modification be if I only want to find one solution and then exit. Thank you in advance

Comment: For each row, `backtracking` calls itself for each column with the next row, so each time you return from a call, you still have loops pending at different levels of recursion. Use `(declaim (optimize (debug 3)))`, recompile all and [trace](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_tracec.htm) the `backtracking` function. You could return a single result either with a non-local exit or by stopping the search as-soon-as-possible, based on the result of recursive invocations to `backtracking`.

Comment: @RichardBerg Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)